# PostgreSQL: Terribly slow ORDER BY with primary key as the ordering key

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a model like this

[image]

with the following table sizes:

```
+------------------+-------------+
| Table            |    Records  |
+------------------+-------------+
| JOB              |         8k  |
| DOCUMENT         |       150k  |
| TRANSLATION_UNIT |      14,5m  |
| TRANSLATION      |      18,3m  |
+------------------+-------------+
```

Now the following query

```
select translation.id
from "TRANSLATION" translation
   inner join "TRANSLATION_UNIT" unit
     on translation.fk_id_translation_unit = unit.id
   inner join "DOCUMENT" document
     on unit.fk_id_document = document.id     
where document.fk_id_job = 11698
order by translation.id asc
limit 50 offset 0
```

takes about **90 seconds** to finish. When I remove the **ORDER BY** and **LIMIT** clauses, it takes **19.5 seconds**. **ANALYZE** had been run on all tables just before executing the query.

For this particular query, these are the numbers of records satisfying the criteria:

```
+------------------+-------------+
| Table            |     Records |
+------------------+-------------+
| JOB              |          1  |
| DOCUMENT         |       1200  |
| TRANSLATION_UNIT |    210,000  |
| TRANSLATION      |    210,000  |
+------------------+-------------+
```

The query plan:

[image]

The query plan for the modification without **ORDER BY** and **LIMIT** is [here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/Qs0).

Database parameters:

```
PostgreSQL 9.2

shared_buffers = 2048MB
effective_cache_size = 4096MB
work_mem = 32MB

Total memory: 32GB
CPU: Intel Xeon X3470 @ 2.93 GHz, 8MB cache
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this query?

**UPDATE**: [Query plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/HHNy) for the same query without **ORDER BY** (but still with the **LIMIT** clause).

Comment: How does the optimiser work for Postgre?  Can you select from your select, for instance, and order this without the optimiser having it's twopenneth?

Comment: Just a lucky guess. Can you try moving the where clause in the join? In this case, just replace the word `where` with `and`.

Comment: @foibs: that won't make any difference. The Postgres optimizer is smart enough to detect that both versions are the same.

Comment: @twoflower: could you also post the execution plan *without* the `order by` (the one that is fast)? Ideally upload it to http://explain.depesz.com they are much more readable that way.

Comment: @foibs The outcome is exactly the same.

Comment: It's instantaneous without `ORDER BY` because it just grabs the first 50 instead of sorting all 210k rows and choosing first 50 from that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added link to the [query plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/HHNy).

Comment: @twoflower This is just a stab at an idea. What if you put main query aka everything but the order by inside a inline view. Put the order by on the inline view.  Does that change anything and still give you what you want?  The order by is causing your plan to loop for a large number of rows. When the order by is removed the loop is only 50. I'm thinking force it to only loop the 50 records you limit in your inline view.  select * from (ALL QUERY HERE WITH LIMIT) as inlineview ORDER BY order inlineview.id asc

Comment: @JustBob -- The way the query is currently written the intent is to get the lowest 50 translation.id rows, whereas your suggested revision grabs an unordered 50 then orders that subset. Those are different things. If the OP actually wants the latter, then your suggestion will certainly be (almost) as fast as the unordered version of the query.

Comment: A query plan including the ORDER BY, would be nice. Otherwise it's hard to see what goes wrong.

Comment: Have you run ANALYZE recently? The linked plan indicates some poor row count estimations.

Comment: @bma Yep your right, twoflower confirmed it won't work for his needs with UPDATE #2.

Comment: @bma `ANALYZE` had been run on each table before executing the query.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit too long for a comment.  You are comparing apples and oranges when you remove the `order by` clause.  Without the `order by`, the processing part of the query only needs to come up with 50 rows.

With the `order by`, all the rows need to be generated before they are sorted and the top few chosen.  How long does the query take if you remove the `order by` *and* the `limit` clause?

The fact that `translation.id` is a primary key does not make a difference, because the processing requires going through several joins (which filter the results).

EDIT:

I wonder how this would work with a CTE to first create the table and then another to sort and fetch the results:

```
with CTE as (
     select translation.id
     from "TRANSLATION" translation
          inner join "TRANSLATION_UNIT" unit
          on translation.fk_id_translation_unit = unit.id
          inner join "DOCUMENT" document
          on unit.fk_id_document = document.id     
     where document.fk_id_job = 11698
    )
select *
from CTE
order by translation.id asc
limit 50 offset 0;
```

Comment: You're right Gordon, those two queries are incomparable. I just ran the query without both `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` and it takes 19.5 seconds. The query plan is [here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/Qs0)

Comment: @twoflower . . . You have a large volume of data.  I am not so familiar with optimization parameters for Postgres, but if you can increase your buffer sizes to use more memory, you might see a performance improvement.

Comment: Yes, the volume is pretty big, that's why I'm not surprised that it takes 19.5 seconds to fetch __all__ the records. What strikes me as odd, however, is that just ordering this data set (cca 212,000 records) adds another 70 seconds.

Comment: I now tried the CTE approach you suggested and it runs for 20-30 seconds, which is considerably faster than the original query. Thank you very much. Is it normal, though, that on a data set 5× smaller (i.e. 40,000 records) it takes 120ms (that is 240× faster)?

Comment: @twoflower . . . Database performance is dependent on many things.  In particular, a key factor is the proportion of processing that can take place in memory.  As disk gets used, performance decreases dramatically.  You may need to allocate more memory to various buffers to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a composite index in place on translation(fk_id_translation_unit, id)? It seems to me that that would help  by avoiding the need to access the translation.id via the table.

Comment: You mean composite index combining the `fk_id_translation_unit` and `id` columns? I don't, but might give it a try.

Comment: The benefit I see is that the translation table itself does not need to be accessed at all in order to retrieve the data required.

Comment: Well, it does, since I need `TRANSLATION.id` in the result set. A guy on a PostgreSQL performance forum just recommended denormalizing the database and adding `fk_id_job` directly to `TRANSLATION`.

Comment: That should be accessible from the index without visiting the table, though.

Comment: I see. The actual query fetches all the columns from `TRANSLATION`.

Comment: Ah, hence the importance of describing the actual problem you're trying to solve ;) Nevertheless, a composite index would allow the sort to take place before retrieving the actual data -- if this doesn't happen then the query could possibly be rewritten to promote the notion to the optimiser. Have you tried adding that index first?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has the same problem. It happened to me and I solved it by changing the index to ordered index. Index was extended by column ID (PK column) and direction of order.

Like that:

```
create index index_name on SCHEMA.TABLE (id asc, (sent_time IS NULL), some_id_ref, type);
```